# How to offset an input voltage of 0V ~ 10V to -400mv ~ +400mv?

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

I have a circuit input which provides a voltage range of 0v to +10v DC. How do I change this output to -400mv ~ +400mv DC ?

Comment: Where do the signal comes from (output impedance of previous block)? Where does it go (input impedance of next block)? What are the supply rails available?

Comment: The DC input signal come from LM358, output via 10Mohm resistor connect to AD8663, Power supply is +5V 0V -5V, thank you.

Comment: 10Mohm ? You mean you have a 10MOhm resistor connected to the input of AD8663? Why? It's huge! That will obviously have an effect on accuracy.

Comment: No , I mean -400mv ~ + 400mv through 10MOhm resistor connected to the OUTPUT of AD8663.

Comment: Well, call me dumb, but now I'm lost. So there is a 10MOhm at the output of AD8663. Where is the other end of this resistor connected to? Please describe the whole system clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this circuit (differential amplifier):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnp3AS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The output voltage is: Vout = R2 / R1 * (V2 - V1)

If you use:

- V2 = your input voltage (0V to +10V)
- V1 = 5V (reference)
- R2/R1 = 8/100

You will obtain +400mV output when Vin is 10V and -400mV when Vin is 0V. I leave to you the consideration about choosing the exact resistance values, the appropriate Op Amp and its power supply.

Comment: Sir, R2 is 8Ω, R1 is 100Ω Right? LM324 or UA741 Which is more suitable?

Comment: In theory, yes. However, I would recommend to use higher values, to reduce your power consumption (I guess 2kOhm and 25kOhm would be good values). Make sure your source impedance is low, otherwise the output will be different. After a quick look, both Op Amp look ok, but I don't know enough about your requirements to be 100% sure. Use an accurate 5V reference as V1 if you want an accurate output.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance and will be purchasing parts for testing.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your source output impedance is \$0\:\Omega\$ and the destination's input impedance is infinite and you have access to both \$\pm 10\:\textrm{V}\$ rails, then something like this would do it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi1mTF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Of course, I'm sure reality impinges and this won't help you for any number of practical reasons you didn't discuss about your circumstances.

---

Updated to include your \$\pm 5\:\textrm{V}\$ supplies:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqbvTr.png)</sup>

If \$R_2=X=47\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$, then \$R_1\approx 56\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$, \$R_3\approx 294\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$, \$R_{TH_{in}}\approx 319\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$, and \$R_{TH_{out}}= 23.5\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$.

---

For those interested, here's a general solution approach (that may be adapted, as needed.) Suppose you know \$V_1\$, \$V_2\$, \$V_{I_{min}}\$, \$V_{I_{max}}\$, \$V_{O_{min}}\$, \$V_{O_{max}}\$, and the value for \$R\$ (which guarantees that the loading on the input will be more than that.) You can obviously then compute \$\Delta V_O = V_{O_{max}} - V_{O_{min}}\$ and \$\Delta V_I = V_{I_{max}} - V_{I_{min}}\$.

The schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbkGAz.png)</sup>

And the values for \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ are then:

$$\begin{align*}
R_1 &= R\cdot\frac{\Delta V_O\cdot\left(V_2-V_1\right)}{V_2\cdot\left(\Delta V_I-\Delta V_O\right)-V_{O_{min}}\cdot V_{I_{max}}+V_{O_{max}}\cdot V_{I_{min}}} \\ \\
R_2 &= R\cdot\frac{\Delta V_O\cdot\left(V_1-V_2\right)}{V_1\cdot\left(\Delta V_I-\Delta V_O\right)-V_{O_{min}}\cdot V_{I_{max}}+V_{O_{max}}\cdot V_{I_{min}}}
\end{align*}$$

Might be useful in a pinch where you know the input range and the output range. If the values aren't both positive then the circuit isn't realizable as shown. But the reason why will probably be obvious, too.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance, but I'm wondering, base in the same of effect, What is the difference between it and the op amplifier ?

Comment: @puby It's just an alternative approach.

Answer (score 1):

Map 0 to +10 V to -2.5 V to +2.5 V by using two equal value resistors and a -5 volt reference.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFeVAe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Attenuate the signal to produce -0.4 volts to +0.4 volts.

In other words add an output resistor to ground. 125 ohm would reduce the -2.5 to +2.5 to -0.5 to +0.5.